# How to get rid of the ` ` in row names in R?

Tags: r

I imported a file into R and let's say the row name is "Hours Studied". Instead of having Hours Studied imported into R, it imports `Hours Studied` with the annoying `` ` ` `` on top of the name. How do I remove it?

I tried doing rownames(data)<- "Hours Studied". But it still returns `` `Hours Studied` `` instead of the desired Hours Studied.

Attached an image in this post for clarification

[image]

Comment: backticks are used when a name is invalid. e.g. starts with a number, has a space etc. just remove the space and it wont need those ticks. You can add labels to dataframes using the Hmisc package, then you can use them to capture the non-valid column name you like

Comment: `rownames(my.df) <- make.names(rownames(my.df), unique=TRUE, allow_ = TRUE)` might also do it, if you're in a hurry.

Comment: You're trying to set the row names to be just a single string, but your issue is with *column* names. Row names need to be unique, so that wouldn't have worked even if changing row names had been your intention.

Comment: Replace spaces with underscores. Try : `names(data) <- gsub(' ', '_', names(data))`

Answer (score 1):

If you use interupted variable names with spaces (e.g. `'my variable'`) rather than continuous variable names with dashes or underscores (e.g. `my_variable`, `my-variable`), R will put "backticks" around the variable or column name to make sure it's clear what is included in the variable name.  If you export the data or plot the data in R those ticks will not be present in the displayed variable name.